# Adzerk vote icons appearing on SO with no adverts present

Tags: bug, advertising

It seems that adzerk voting icons are appearing on SO pages where no ads are present. In the following screenshot, I kept seeing them appear when my cursor passed over a small area above the careers section and not in connection with it.

Naturally, I upvoted no adverts, but I suspect this is a bug in the logic:

[image]

Looking at the source, it seems the adzerk code is included even when no ads are being displayed. Is this intentional? Shouldn't it be removed when no ads are displayed?

Upon further investigation, mousing over an entire `div` is causing it:

[image]

When there are no ads present, I can always repeat this and under different tags.

Comment: Aren't you looking at this the wrong way around? You should be asking why you don't have any ads! Stop asking for more ads... :-).

Comment: A user encouraging advertising... Surely that would be a first! :)

Comment: Do you have adblocker enabled?

Comment: @LanceRoberts No, I don't block ads either on computer or at router level.

Comment: Yup, can reproduce and if that's not a bug then nothing is a bug.

Comment: Just found that it's already reported before.

Comment: Meh. Couldn't find that due to creative titling. More than a month old too... [raises eyebrows]

Comment: @nickhar well, you *could* browse the recent [meta-tag:advertising] questions looking for a report but you're right it wasn't trivial to find.